# Laravel SqlSrvDB error : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: laravel, sql-server-2008

I have issue when connected to SQL SERVER DB 2008R2 on laravel.

This is my error:-

> SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   (SQL: select * from [contact] where [vduid] = 578ff36e00000000ac149062232f0002)

config inside `database.php` file:-

```
'sybaseuepg-aluno' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => 'x.x.x.x',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',

    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

Comment: are you able to run other queries? can you run the same query directly on the server?

Comment: yes i can run the same query from Database GUI it's work fine but don't know i get this error only in laravle ?!

Comment: i would check the error logs on the sql server

Comment: problem solved with Node.js and GoLang everything works like a charm, really good bye php